# Navigation controller's view controller button taking me to entirely new window as opposed to the next page. Why is this happening?

Tags: xcode

Control clicked the button and connected it through action segue "show." Can't even see the back button when I open the app, it just opens the entirely new window. Thank you for your help!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucmND.jpg

Comment: Can you post your code what have you implemented?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Qpv3v4L

Answer (score 0):

Now above Xcode 11.X it shows Show Segue like that.
 You can achieve your desired result by 2 ways.
 1. Embed your First controller in Navigation Controller like shown in Image. 
[image]

Or 2. You can Set TopBar to None like shown in this Image. 
[image]